# Two infinite dimensional spaces whose Banach-Mazur distance equal to 1(details in the proof)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Sorry for this "duplicated" question. Two years ago, there was a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446008/the-banach-mazur-distance-is-not-reached)
concerning about Banach-Mazur distance between infinite dimensional spaces and the answer was accepted. But I am really a beginner for Banach space theory and don't quite understand the answer given there.

The question is

> Let $(p_n)$ and $(q_n)$ be two disjoint sequences, dense in $[1,1.5]$ such that $p_1=1$. Take $X=\left(\sum \ell_{p_n}^5\right)_2$ and $Y =\left(\sum \ell_{q_n}^5\right)_2$. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are isomophic but not isometric to each other and $d_{BM}(X,Y)=1$.

He gives a hint to the proof of $d_{BM}(X,Y)=1$:

> The Banach-Mazur distance is $1$ because for every $\epsilon>0$ the interval $[1,1.5]$ can be partitioned into subintervals of size $\epsilon$, each of which meets both sequences countably many times.

I know we are supposed to find an isomophism $T:X\rightarrow Y$ such that $\|T\| \cdot \|T^{-1}\|\le 1+\epsilon$. But there are two maps $T \text{ and } T^{-1}$ here, which makes the proof very difficult . Maybe I should fix $\|T^{-1}\|=1$ by scaling, but this doesn't reduce any workload for me.

For the proof of the non-isometric part, he was trying to show that $Y$
is not strictly convex. However, I don't believe that the second half of the following inequality is true:

> $$\sum \left\|\frac{y_n+z_n}{2}\right\|_{q_n}^2 \le \sum \left( \frac{\|y_n\|_{q_n}+\|z_n\|_{q_n}}{2}\right)^2 \le    \frac14 \sum \left\|y_n\right\|_{q_n}^2 + \frac14 \sum \left\|z_n\right\|_{q_n}^2 \tag2$$

I think it should be

> $$\sum \left\|\frac{y_n+z_n}{2}\right\|_{q_n}^2 \le \sum \left( \frac{\|y_n\|_{q_n}+\|z_n\|_{q_n}}{2}\right)^2 \le    \frac12 \sum \left\|y_n\right\|_{q_n}^2 + \frac12 \sum \left\|z_n\right\|_{q_n}^2 \tag2$$

But then his proof doesn't seem to work.

Every answer and helpful hint will be appreciated! And if you know any other examples for the same purpose, please feel free to post them.

Comment: Can you also include the definition of $\sum \ell_{p_n}^5$? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnMa sorry for the late reply. Please look at the proposition 1.18 of the following link for the definition http://www.math.tamu.edu/~schlump/sections1.1,1.2_math655.pdf

Comment: Sorry, I tried too hard to avoid typing square roots when writing that proof. Fixed now.

Comment: @NormalHuman Thx~~~I am looking forward to your solution!

Comment: I meant that I corrected the algebraic error in the solution you linked to (which was posted by me; I had a different account back then). I think the correction should resolve your question.

Comment: @NormalHuman   Thx~~but how to show that $d_{BM}(X,Y)=1$

Comment: It's written there... Partition the interval $[1,1.5]$ into subintervals of size $\epsilon$. Each will contain countably many summands, for both $X$ and $Y$. Put any bijection between these summands. The norm of this bijection  is $1+O(\epsilon)$, both ways.

Comment: @NormalHuman Yes, I noticed that hint and had spent two weeks working on that.....I have trouble in showing that the norm of bijection is no greater than $1+\epsilon$ (or $1+O(\epsilon)$ as you said). Could you show me more details for that?

Comment: It seemed more logical to add details to the original question, so that the proof is in the same place. [I just did this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1501430)